# Why numerical solution of hydrogen Schrodinger equation diverged in higher energy levels?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hydrogen

I am studying Computational Physics by Thijssen. I also read this notebook https://github.com/tamuhey/python_1d_dft/blob/master/numpy_1ddft.ipynb. Then I changed this notebook to solve this Schrodinger equation

$$\hat{H} =  - \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} - \frac{1}{r}$$

The code is adapted  to

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

n_grid=1000
x=np.linspace(1e-9,50,n_grid+1)[1:]

h=x[1]-x[0]
D=-np.eye(n_grid)+np.diagflat(np.ones(n_grid-1),1)
D = D / h

D2=D.dot(-D.T)
D2[-1,-1]=D2[0,0]

X=np.diagflat(1/x)

eig_harm, psi_harm = np.linalg.eigh(-D2/2-X)

for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(x,psi_harm[:,i], label=f"{eig_harm[0] / eig_harm[i]:.4f}")
    plt.legend(loc=1)[1]][1]
```

[image: The solution of the Schrodinger equation]

It seems that the first five solutions are correct with $\frac{1}{n^2}$ trend. But why the six and higher energy levels leave this trend?

Comment: Does that code you posted even work? I'm seeing a bunch of misplaced square braces....

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that error.

Comment: To me, it is no surprise that higher energy levels diverge from the correct results since you set up the upper bound for x with x=50. I guess you can improve higher energy results through elevating 50 to higher values.

Comment: Following up on Andy's comment, I tested your code (fixing the errors you left in) with the upper bound of 90 and it shows the expected ~36 value.